# Why isn't my JavaScript loop working?

Tags: javascript

The loop is supposed to take the price of each book, add it to the total, and then put the average on the page for each book until the user enters in "N"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ct = 1;
var yesORno = "Y";
while (yesORno = "Y"){
    book = prompt("What is the price of book #" + ct, 0);
    total = parseInt(book) + total;
    ans = total / ct;
    document.write("<p>With book #" + ct +" The average is " + ans + "</p>");
    ct = ct + 1;
    yesORno = prompt("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)", "")
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's an infinite loop.

Comment: `while (yesORno = "Y"){` should be `while (yesORno === "Y"){` Use http://jshint.com/ to find common errors in your code.

Comment: (optional) you should also check for "y"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change your while condition to:

```
while (yesORno == "Y")
```

Using only `=` will make it assign 'Y' value to yesORno and return itself, which is evaluated as true and makes it run forever.

Answer (score 3):

```
var ct = 1;
var yesORno = "Y";
while (yesORno == "Y"){
    book = prompt("What is the price of book #" + ct, 0);
    total = parseInt(book) + total;
    ans = total / ct;
    document.write("<p>With book #" + ct +" The average is " + ans + "</p>");
    ct = ct + 1;
    yesORno = prompt("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)", "")
}
```

Look at the third line.

Answer (score 3):

Like others stated, you have used the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==` or the strict equality operator `===`.

However, you could also refactor your code using a do while loop instead. That would remove the need of having a `yesORno` variable.

```
do {
    //...
} while(prompt("Would you like to continue? (Y/N)", "") === 'Y')
```